# WooCommerce Price Format - Intermittent Syntax Error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following WooCommerce variation price format function in my theme's functions.php file:

```
function wc_wc20_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {
    // Main Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
    $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    // Sale Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
    sort( $prices );
    $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    if ( $price !== $saleprice ) {
        $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . '</del> <ins>' . $price . '</ins>';
    }

    return $price;
}
```

This was listed online in a few places such as: https://gist.github.com/kloon/8981075  and a number of people have reported it working for them. It works for me, however I intermittently get a syntax error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 12

Line 12 is the line just before sort( $prices ); - the line that sets the $prices variable to an array the second time.

I don't see any syntax issues here. The strange thing is this doesn't happen all the time. It happens sometimes when I visit a product category and then return to the site homepage - but not every time. Everything works as expected, except this syntax error totally breaks the site when it comes up.

*EDIT*

After some further debugging, here's an update:

Directly before the line in question, I'm logging the output of $product->get_variation_regular_price() to a text file:

```
$file = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/errors.txt'; 
$open = fopen( $file, "a" ); 

ob_start();
print_r($product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ));
$min = ob_get_clean();
$write = fputs( $open, "min: " . $min ); 

ob_start();
print_r($product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ));
$max = ob_get_clean();
$write = fputs( $open, "max: " . $max);

fclose( $open );
```

This time, the error reads:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$min' (T_VARIABLE), expecting
>   ',' or ')' in wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 19

Line 19 is the first print_r statement.

My errors.txt now contains this:

> min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min:
>   22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 24.99max: 24.99min: 24.99max: 24.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 24.99max: 24.99min: 24.99max: 24.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 24.99max: 24.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 24.99max: 24.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 24.99max: 24.99min: 24.99max: 24.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 24.99max: 24.99min: 24.99max: 24.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 24.99max: 24.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 22.99max: 22.99min: 25.99max: 25.99min: 24.99max: 24.99min: 24.99max: 24.99

I'm not sure which specific numbers were from that refresh as it took quite a few refreshes for the syntax error to appear, but it should be the mix/max values near the end of that data. I haven't seen anything in the data that looks out of the ordinary, it all appears correct to me.

@Mukesh - I'm sure it works fine for most people in their environments. Unfortunately it works only intermittently for me (about 1 of every 20 refreshes it throws the syntax error instead of rendering the page). Unfortunately the site is still under development on a staging server, so I can't share a URL with you, only my code and errors.

Comment: have you check what returns your passed arguments (`get_variation_regular_price()`) when this happens?

Comment: it's work fine. send your live url

Comment: I've edited the question to add additional info based on your comments.